# Null pointer after capturing image using android camera in nexus 5

Tags: android

In my application, I am using android device camera to capture my image. In some device it works fine but not all, I just tested it LG nexus 5 E960, after I captured the image it always end crash without able to save the result this is my code:

```
  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);



  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent returnimage) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, returnimage);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = returnimage.getData();

            String stringUri;
            stringUri = selectedImage.toString();
            Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondpage.class);
             i1.putExtra("Stringuri",stringUri );
            startActivity(i1);


        }
        break;
```

And my logcat is:

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,
     request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity 
     {com.photostikers/com.photostikers.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
     02-13 12:27:54.315: E/AndroidRuntime(28759):  at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
     02-13 12:27:54.315: E/AndroidRuntime(28759):  at  
     android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2775)
     02-13 12:27:54.315: E/AndroidRuntime(28759):  ... 12 more
     02-13 12:27:54.315: E/AndroidRuntime(28759): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     02-13 12:27:54.315: E/AndroidRuntime(28759):  at 
     com.photostikers.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:335)
     02-13 12:27:54.315: E/AndroidRuntime(28759):  at 
     android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
     02-13 12:27:54.315: E/AndroidRuntime(28759):  at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
     02-13 12:27:54.315: E/AndroidRuntime(28759):  ... 13 more
```

Comment: What is line 335 of MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondpage.class);
        i1.putExtra("bitmap",imageBitmap );
        startActivity(i1);
    }
}
```

And in `Secondpage Activity`

Get the image like

```
Bitmap bitImage = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bitmap");
your_image+_view.setImageBitmap(bitImage);
```

Go through the Android Developer Document for [Get the Thumbnail](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView)

Answer (score 1):

It seams to be a common problem in nexus5.

Instead of this:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
```

Try this:

```
Uri mPhotoUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
        new ContentValues());
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoUri);
startActivityForResult(intent,CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_CONTENT_RESOLVER);
```

take a look at this: 
http://cssmay.com/question/tag/tag-camera , I think that it can help you a lot.

Comment: thanks dyna for reply and what should do in activityonresult after adding this code and what is mphotouri...

Comment: Uri is the URI where you are going to put the image. I'll update the answer

Comment: please also clear what should do in activity on result after implented this code..with example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47421/discussion-between-user3098271-and-dyna)

Comment: line 335 is i1.putExtra("Stringuri",stringUri );
the whole code is if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 

Uri selectedImage = returnimage.getData(); 
//Uri selectedImage = getIntent().getData(); 
// String str = (String) returnimage.getExtras().get("data"); 
// coverpath.setText(selectedImage.getPath()); 
String stringUri; 
stringUri = selectedImage.toString(); 
Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondpage.class); 
i1.putExtra("Stringuri",stringUri ); 
startActivity(i1);